# How to find the SQL Server databse Last used?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find the SQL Server database Last used by DB users. ... give you whodunnit information and you can group by to get min/MAX event times

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        DB_NAME(database_id) AS TheDatabase,
        last_user_seek,
        last_user_scan,
        last_user_lookup,
        last_user_update
    FROM 
        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
)
SELECT
    ServerRestartedDate = (SELECT CREATE_DATE FROM sys.databases where name='tempdb'),
    x.TheDatabase,
    MAX(x.last_read) AS  last_read,
    MAX(x.last_write) AS last_write
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TheDatabase, last_user_seek AS last_read, NULL AS last_write 
     FROM 
         myCTE

     UNION ALL  

     SELECT 
         TheDatabase, last_user_scan, NULL 
     FROM 
         myCTE

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         TheDatabase, last_user_lookup, NULL 
     FROM 
         myCTE

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         TheDatabase, NULL, last_user_update 
     FROM 
         myCTE) AS x
GROUP BY 
    TheDatabase
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.